# AngularJS input from mongoose module decimals

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I have a mongoose model containing a salesPrice type number. Since mongoose doesn't support decimals I created a setter and a getter like this

```
function getSalesPrice(num){
    if (num)
        return (num/100).toFixed(2);
    else
        return (0).toFixed(2);
}

function setSalesPrice(num){
    return num*100;
}
```

In Angular view i want to view value with decimals, so e.g. I store 99 in model meaning $0.99 
only in my form will show as 99

```
<label for="salesPrice" class="col-md-2 control-label">Salesprice</label>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" data-ng-model="asset.salesData.salesPrice" id="salesPrice" placeholder="Sales price in USD">
</div>
```

What's way to work with this correctly?

Comment: First of all, mongoose definitely supports decimals. You should use the Number type, and then just store a decimal in it (this corresponds to Javascript's Number type). Can you please be more specific about what your problem is? You have 99 stored in mongoose and you want it to show as $0.99 in your angular form?

Comment: there are various decimal separators like . in USA and , in Europe for that reason we now take it as string, parse it and multiply by 100 to store it. If I enter indeed 0.99 and store in mongo it is ok but 0,99 is not

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying what you meant by "Mongo can't store decimals." Am I correct in assuming that what you intend to do is store the value in Mongodb as "99" (and internally in the angular "model" as "99") but display it as "$0.99"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly, then the best way to solve this problem is to use angular's built-in 'currency' filter. If you have a $resource that returns values in decimal format from e.g. mongoose, then you can display the values like:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values">
    {{ value | currency }}
</div>
```

And achieve a locale specific (based on the browser viewing it) result.

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vIijYhwR4GEXyBl3rNsx?p=preview) is an example plnkr showing this off (without a mock resource)

Comment: thanks that works but how to use on an input element?